# Angular testing with Jest and inject() function

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, jestjs

I want to test an Angular component with Jest and without initiating a TestBed. I want to do a pure javascript test without Angular context if possible. As described in the documentation https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-services

```js
describe('ValueService', () => {
  let service: ValueService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new ValueService();
  });

  test('#getValue should return real value', () => {
    expect(service.getValue()).toBe('real value');
  });
```

It doesn't work if the component or service uses `{ inject} from '@angular/core'`.

```js
export class ValueService () { 
  protected destroyRef: DestroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
  [...]
}
```

In this case I got this error:

```
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, 
factory function, field initialiser, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext'.
 See https://angular.io/errors/NG0203 for more information.
```

Is it possible to disable angular DI during testing? or mock inject() behaviour?

I'm also trying another approach using `runInInjectionContext`, but I haven't found a way to mock all the providers.
.

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    runInInjectionContext(Injector.create({ providers: [{ provide: any, useValue: jest.mock }] }), () => {
      service = new ValueService();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `jest.mock('@angular/core');` let me to mock the DI of the angular component. Mock condition must be defined before describe(...).

```js
jest.mock('@angular/core');

describe('ValueService', () => {
  let service: ValueService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new ValueService();
  });

  test('#getValue should return real value', () => {
    expect(service.getValue()).toBe('real value');
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you rely on Dependency Injection you should level the `TestBed` features.

```
service = TestBed.inject(ValueService)
```

If your service is not `providedIn:'root' you will need to setup the TestModule with :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({providers: [ValueService]});
```

Comment: I don't need DI in my tests. I don't want to do an integration test with a TestBed. But i got some problems with inject() function.

Comment: Yes, I understood inject() is part of Angular DI. I am looking for a solution to do pure javascript tests with jest on components who rely on this function, by disabling Angular DI. Anyway i find a solution with jest.mock module. 
I try to avoid Test bed when possible like https://vugar-005.medium.com/angular-unit-testing-without-testbed-ed7832df8ad9 or Angular documentation (link in post)